Why is transpose not equal to inverse in general?
Let $\phi: X \rightarrow Y$ be a linear map between finite dimensional real vector spaces, let $p:X \rightarrow X^*$ and $q: Y \rightarrow Y^*$ map from basis to dual basis, and let $\varphi: Y^* \rightarrow X^*$ be the induced map that sends $\varphi : f \mapsto f\circ \phi$. Let $\dim X = \dim Y$ so that all matrices are square. For simplicity, also assume $\phi$ is surjective, so everything is invertible:

The matrices of $p$ and $q$ are identity matrices, and the matrix of $\varphi$ is the transpose of the matrix of $\phi$. So (denoting the matrix of a map $T$ as $[T]$) if $M$ is the matrix of $\phi$, we can write $I = [p]= [\phi][q][\varphi] = MIM^T = MM^T$, which implies that any arbitrary invertible real square matrix is orthogonal.
This is obviously wrong - but where did I go wrong? Does the diagram not commute? Is the above not valid because I'm implicitly assuming different bases or something?
Thanks in advance!

@Nic what he wrote is the definition of the transpose

When you choose a basis (and a dual basis) you are fixing isomorphisms to $\mathbb R^n$, but now you’re working with the same vector space. If I choose $(1,0),(0,1)$ as one basis, and $(1,1),(1,-1)$ as another basis for $\mathbb R^2$ then define a matrix which takes a basis vector to a basis vector, then that sure does look like the identity map in these bases, but that’s really just because of how we labeled things.

See the interesting answer of @fimpellizzeri here

It may be instructive to work through the simplest counterexample: $X = Y$ are real one-dimensional vector spaces and $\phi$ is multiplication by $2$: Not just to note $2^2 \neq 1$, but to grok, in the sense of measurement, why scaling has reciprocal effects on a vector space and its dual.

The fundamental problem is that your square does not commute. Possibly the most obvious example of this occurs, when $\phi$ is not injective. After all, in that case the composition $\varphi\circ q\circ\phi$ won't be injective either. But $p$ is an isomorphism by its definition, hence injective. Consider the case $\phi=0$, if this is not enough!
The vertical arrows are "unnatural" in the sense that their definition depends on the choice of bases for $X$ and $Y$. And we can change one or the other (or both) independently from each other. On the other hand the horizontal arrows depend only on the transformation $\phi$, and their meaning is independent of the above choice of bases. Anyway, it should be clear by now that for most choices of bases the resulting diagram won't commute.
Instead of the (non)-commutative diagram, the definition of $\phi$ amounts to the identity: for all $x\in X, f\in Y^∗$ we have
$$\varphi(f)(x)=f(\phi(x)),$$
which is just a rewriting of $\varphi(f)=f\circ\phi$. Nothing there ties this to any mappings from $X$ to $X^*$ and/or $Y$ to $Y^*$.

Mostly echoing @JyrkiLahtonen's answer, but adding a few things:
The (typical) non-commutativity of that square is worse than the non-canonical-ness of the isomorphism of a finite-dimensional vector space and its dual (depending on choices of bases...)
Namely, even if we decide to look at (a category of real or complex) vector-spaces-with-inner-products, the canonical isomorphism (conjugate-linear, in the complex case) of $V$ to $V^*$ does not give commuting squares. I confess that I first became aware of this only relatively recently when idly thinking about the Riesz-Frechet isomorphism of a Hilbert space with its dual. I'd thought that surely this would be good enough to give commuting squares. But, no, as Jyrki observes, already in the one-dimensional case (!!!), most vector space maps do not give commuting squares. Crazy.
Oop, and, belatedly, I see that @AndrewHuang made this observation in a comment.
